# org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to read very large excel files (say 5GB) from S3bucket. but I am getting org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException for files more than 10Mb. I am using Apache poi. I need to extract data from multiple sheets seperately inside the input excel file after reading. So, I can't use SXSSF as it reads whole data into single sheet. Can anyone suggest me a way to sort my issue!!

I tried Apache poi, all types of workbooks (xssfWorkbook, sxssf,etc.,) nothing worked out I am unable to fetch data from excel. I tried to print sheet names it worked for below 10Mb not for above